# Export json from Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

As we can download json file at Firebase RTDB console, are there any way to export json file of Firestore collection/document data?

One of my main objectives is to compare data before/after updating document.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There is not, you'd need to come up with your own process such as querying a collection and looping over everything.

## Update

As of August 7th, 2018, we do have a [managed export system](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/export-import) that allows you to dump your data into a GCS bucket. While this isn't JSON, it is a format that is the same as Cloud Datastore uses, so BigQuery understands it. This means you can then [import it into BigQuery](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-cloud-datastore).

Comment: Good news. import and export your Cloud Firestore data. Checkout the [blog](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2018/08/more-cloud-firestore-improvements.html) and [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/export-import) for more info

Comment: @dan-mcgrath can you point to any information on sub-collections and how to be able to effectively query those once in BigQuery?

Comment: What format is the exported file, and how could one see the contents?

Comment: How can i export the dump to json format and and is there a way to zip all the dump files?

Comment: I cannot seem to find any information on what format the Firestore export is in. All options for file type in the BigQuery import UI give an error when I try to import the exported Firestore file.

Comment: I found these comments while looking for an answer on the same question, how to view the contents of a Firestore export. There is a separate Firebase help article that tells you how to schedule daily Firestore exports for backup purposes. What the article does not tell you is that, if you are exporting all collections, then you will be unable to open the export file in BigQuery. Instead you need to import it back into Firestore using the Firestore Import/Export page in the GCP console. If you don't want to overwrite your existing Firestore, you can create a new Firebase project to import to.

Answer (score 52):

Google made it harder than it needed to be, so the community found a workaround. If you have `npm` installed, you can do this:

#### Export

```
npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-export -a credentials.json -b backup.json
```

#### Import

```
npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-import -a credentials.json -b backup.json
```

[Source](https://github.com/jloosli/node-firestore-import-export)

Comment: This is the simplest for grabbing data in json format, and working as of this date. You'll need to get GCP service account credentials as seen at 
https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production
  <br/>More docs: https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-export-import

Comment: That worked beautifully, thanks a lot! And thanks @ezaspi as well for the comment re: credentials

Comment: This command works great but on running this command does it count as a reads/writes to the firestore?

Comment: @sh_ark yes it counts towards your project's read/writes

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: how to setup "credential.json" file? I've downloaded the file from firebase service account settings but where to put it, because while running this command, I'm getting error saying can't find credential.json

Comment: @KevalLangalia Use the `-a` argument to point to the location of the file. The given example assumes that the `credentials.json` file resides is in the current folder.

Comment: @GunarGessner well, I had credentials.json in same folder location but anyway, I decided to use `Firefoo` app to export the collections, and it worked! Appreciate your help.

Comment: Does this work on the spark plan of firestore? I think I read somewhere that you dont get access to some GCP feature until you provide creditCard details

Answer (score 39):

I just wrote a backup and restore for Firestore. You can have a try on my GitHub.

https://github.com/dalenguyen/firestore-backup-restore

Thanks,

Comment: amazing  tysm

Comment: This is easiest and best solution. Thanks

Answer (score 15):

I've written a tool that traverses the collections/documents of the database and exports everything into a single json file. Plus, it will import the same structure as well (helpful for cloning/moving Firestore databases). Since I've had a few colleagues use the code, I figured I would publish it as an NPM package. Feel free to try it and give some feedback.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-firestore-import-export

Comment: Excellent best package I have found for this so far, especially the import very useful for multiple environment scenarios. Also I see you have to specify the path to credential file in the command would it be useful to have it first check for path in the environment variable  GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS otherwise can be overridden via the path parameter.

Comment: Also I put this in my package.json so I can just run "npm run firestore-export" or "import"

Comment: @wchoward I like the environment approach...I'll add that for the next version

Comment: @wchoward I added GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS support in version 0.8.0...check it out and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: If i export a collection with huge data size its gives out of memory error

Comment: Thanks for this, but it already fails with ~100k registers. FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory

Answer (score 10):

If someone wants a solution using **Python 2** or **3**.

Edit: note that this does not backup the rules

Fork it on https://github.com/RobinManoli/python-firebase-admin-firestore-backup

First install and setup Firebase Admin Python SDK: https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup

Then install it in your python environment:

```
pip install firebase-admin
```

Install the Firestore module:

```
pip install google-cloud-core
pip install google-cloud-firestore
```

(from [ImportError: Failed to import the Cloud Firestore library for Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48264536/importerror-failed-to-import-the-cloud-firestore-library-for-python))

Python Code

```ph
# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-

import firebase_admin
from firebase_admin import credentials, firestore
import json

cred = credentials.Certificate('xxxxx-adminsdk-xxxxx-xxxxxxx.json') # from firebase project settings
default_app = firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred, {
    'databaseURL' : 'https://xxxxx.firebaseio.com'
})

db = firebase_admin.firestore.client()

# add your collections manually
collection_names = ['myFirstCollection', 'mySecondCollection']
collections = dict()
dict4json = dict()
n_documents = 0

for collection in collection_names:
    collections[collection] = db.collection(collection).get()
    dict4json[collection] = {}
    for document in collections[collection]:
        docdict = document.to_dict()
        dict4json[collection][document.id] = docdict
        n_documents += 1

jsonfromdict = json.dumps(dict4json)

path_filename = "/mypath/databases/firestore.json"
print "Downloaded %d collections, %d documents and now writing %d json characters to %s" % ( len(collection_names), n_documents, len(jsonfromdict), path_filename )
with open(path_filename, 'w') as the_file:
    the_file.write(jsonfromdict)
```

Comment: Very useful and quick for local exports

Answer (score 8):

There is an npm for firestore export / import

**Project to export**
Goto -> project settings -> Service account -> Generate new private key -> save it as exportedDB.json

**Project to import**
Goto -> project settings -> Service account -> Generate new private key -> save it as importedDB.json

run these 2 commands from the folder where u saved the files

**Export:**
npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-export -a exportedDB.json -b backup.json

**Import:**
npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-import -a importedDB.json -b backup.json

Answer (score 3):

Firestore is still early in its development so please check the [docs on backups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/backups) for any information pertaining to Firestore.

I found this npm package, [node-firestore-backup](https://github.com/steadyequipment/node-firestore-backup), to be easy and useful.

Note that the `--accountCredentials path/to/credentials/file.json` is referring to a service account key json file that you can get by following instructions from https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/application-default-credentials.

> 1. Go to the API Console Credentials page.
> 2. From the project drop-down, select your project.
> 3. On the Credentials page, select the Create credentials drop-down, then select Service account key.
> 4. From the Service account drop-down, select an existing service account or create a new one.
> 5. For Key type, select the JSON key option, then select Create. The file automatically downloads to your computer.
> 6. Put the *.json file you just downloaded in a directory of your choosing. This directory must be private (you can't let anyone get access to this), but accessible to your web server code.

Comment: If the collection data size is big it is crashing with out of memory errror

Comment: This is not a good solution for an averange database. With ~100k registers already fails.

Answer (score 3):

It works for me.

I used [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started?authuser=0#deploy-functions-to-a-production-environment) to export all data in Firestore to JSON format. The function that I was used:

```js
exports.exportFirestore2Json = functions.https.onRequest((request, response) => {
    db.collection("data").get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        const orders = [];
        var order = null

         querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {
             order = doc.data();
             orders.push(order);
         });

         response.send(JSON.stringify(orders))

         return true
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        return false
    });
})
```

Then, go to https://your-project-id.cloudfunctions.net/exportFirestore2Json you will see something like this

[image]

Comment: Does it work for a large database (5-10 GB)?

Comment: @VeereshDevireddy I don't test this case yet.

Comment: I think the limit is 10 MB

Answer (score 3):

**for dumping json from your local to firestoreDB:**

```
npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-import -a credentials.json -b backup.json
```

**for downloading data from firestoreDB to your local:**

```
npx -p node-firestore-import-export firestore-export -a credentials.json -b backup.json
```

to generate credentials.json, go to project settings -> service accounts -> generate a private key.

Comment: Best and easiest method, especially if you already have a service account on your pc.

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can, you did not need to start billing in your firebase console. There is a great npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/firestore-export-import with this you can export and import firestore collection and documents easily. Just follow some steps:

-Get your service account key
Open Firebase console > Project settings > Service accounts > generate new private key

rename the downloaded file with serviceAccountKey.json

-Now create a new folder and  index.js file.

-Paste you servicekey.json in this folder

-Now install this package

```
npm install firestore-export-import
```

OR

```bash
yarn add firestore-export-import
```

#### Exporting data from firebase

```js
const { initializeApp} =  require('firestore-export-import')

const  serviceAccount  =  require('./serviceAccountKey.json')

const  appName  =  '[DEFAULT]'

initializeApp(serviceAccount, appName)

const  fs  =  require('fs');

const { backup } =  require('firestore-export-import')
//backup('collection name')

backup('users').then((data) =>
{
    const  json  =  JSON.stringify(data);

    //where collection.json is your output file name.
    fs.writeFile('collection.json', json, 'utf8',()=>{

    console.log('done');

})

});
```

Execute node index.js and you should see a new collection.json file with your collection and documents in it. If it looks a little messy pretty format it online with
https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer

This index.js was just a very basic configuration which exports the whole collection with everything in it, read their documentation you could do queries and much more!

#### Importing data to firebase

```js
const { initializeApp,restore } =  require('firestore-export-import')

const  serviceAccount  =  require('./serviceAccountKey.json')
const  appName  =  '[DEFAULT]'

initializeApp(serviceAccount, appName)
restore('collection.json', {
//where refs is an array of key items
    refs: ['users'],
    //autoParseDates to parse dates if documents have timestamps
    autoParseDates: true,

    },()=>{

console.log('done');
})
```

After execution you should see your firestore populated with collection users!

Comment: something is missing in code. getting error "initializeApp() is not a function", can you help by mentioning exact code or any import i need to do in code?

Comment: var admin = require("firebase-admin");
const  serviceAccount  =  require('./serviceAccountKey.json')
admin.initializeApp({
  credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
  databaseURL: "https://playbae-3fdc0.firebaseio.com"
});


const  fs  =  require('fs');

const { backup } =  require('firestore-export-import')
//backup('collection name')

backup('Users').then((data) =>
{
    const  json  =  JSON.stringify(data);

    //where collection.json is your output file name.
    fs.writeFile('collection.json', json, 'utf8',()=>{

    console.log('done');

})
});

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a blank folder (call it *firebaseImportExport* ) and run **npm init**
2. Go to the source Firebase project -> Settings -> Service Accounts
3. Click on the **Generate new private key** button and rename the file as source.json and put it in the *firebaseImportExport* folder
4. Do the same (step 2 & 3) for the destination project and rename the file as destination.json
5. Install the `npm i firebase-admin` npm package.
6. Write the following code in the ***index.js***

```js
const firebase = require('firebase-admin');

var serviceAccountSource = require("./source.json");
var serviceAccountDestination = require("./destination.json");

const sourceAdmin = firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccountSource),
    databaseURL: "https://**********.firebaseio.com" // replace with source
});

const destinationAdmin = firebase.initializeApp({
    credential: firebase.credential.cert(serviceAccountDestination),
    databaseURL: "https://$$$$$.firebaseio.com"
  }, "destination");

const collections = [ "books", "authors",   ...]; // replace with your collections

    var source = sourceAdmin.firestore();
    var destination = destinationAdmin.firestore();
   collections.forEach(colName => {
    source.collection(colName).get().then(function(querySnapshot) {
        querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
            destination.collection(colName).doc(doc.id).set({...doc.data()});
        });
    });
   });
```

Answer (score 1):

Documents can also be downloaded as JSON via the [REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/use-rest-api#making_rest_calls).

This is an example using curl in conjunction with the Cloud SDK to obtain an access token:

```bash
curl -H "Authorization: Bearer "$(gcloud auth print-access-token) \
  "https://firestore.googleapis.com/v1/projects/$PROJECT/databases/(default)/documents/$COLLECTION/$DOCUMENT"
```

Answer (score 0):

Open any of your clientside firebase apps (React, Angular, etc.). Use this code anywhere to log console and copy

```js
const products = await db
  .collection("collectionName")
  .where("time", ">", new Date("2020-09-01"))
  .get()


const json = JSON.stringify(products.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data() })))
console.log(json)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found an easier solution. There is a tool called [Firefoo](https://firefoo.app/). It lists all the collection documents along with created users with multiple providers(email & password, phone number, google, facebook etc). You can export data in JSON & CSV along with that you can view the data in simplified format like Table, Tree, JSON.

Note:- You don't have to go through all the process for importing or exporting data from your firebase console.

Answer (score 0):

Create a blank folder (Ex: firebaseImportExport ) and run npm init

Go to the source Firebase project -> Settings -> Service Accounts

Click on the Generate new private key button and rename the file as appConfig.json and put it in the firebaseImportExport folder

add packages

```
npm install firestore-export-import
```

create an index.js file.

paste the below code

```
const { initializeFirebaseApp } = require('firestore-export-import')

const  serviceAccount  =  require('./appConfig.json')

const  appName  =  '[DEFAULT]'

const firestore = initializeFirebaseApp(serviceAccount, appName)

const  fs  =  require('fs');

const { backup } = require('firestore-export-import')
//backup('collection name')

backup(firestore, 'collection-name').then((data) =>
{
    const  json  =  JSON.stringify(data);

    //where collection.json is your output file name.
    fs.writeFile('collection.json', json, 'utf8',()=>{

    console.log('done');

})

});
```

Answer (score 0):

firestore-export-import has worked well for me, but here's a smaller version that I use when the structure of the firebase docs is simple.

```
const fs = require('fs')
const {initializeApp} = require('firebase/app')
const {getFirestore, collection, getDocs} = require('firebase/firestore')
const firebaseConfig = {
    // YOUR API KEY CONFIG
}
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
const db = getFirestore(app)

async function getAllData() {
    const docs = new Map()
    const profiles = await getDocs(collection(db, 'profiles'))
    profiles.forEach((doc) => {
        docs[doc.id] = doc.data()
    })
    const collections = new Map()
    collections['profiles'] = docs
    const fullDb = new Map()
    fullDb['__collections__'] = collections

    return fullDb
}

getAllData().then(fullDb => {
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(fullDb, null, 2)
    fs.writeFile('./backup.json', jsonString, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err)
        } else {
            console.log('export complete')
        }
    })
})
```

Comment: Good Answer, please explain in more details why you would prefer this structure, if there's any reason

Comment: Mostly I thought there should be a clear, simple example here that was an alternative to using firebase-export-import. It's handy if you only want a subset of the collections or if you want to perform any data transformations, etc. Here's an example that outputs an array instead of map, including the doc id in the object:

`const profiles = [];  const docs = await getDocs(collection(db, 'profiles'));  docs.forEach((doc) => {
 const profile = doc.data()
 profile.userId = doc.id
 profiles.push(profile)
});`