# Export Firestore backups in .json

Tags: json, google-cloud-firestore

Is it possible to export Firestore backups in .json format? (that do NOT require BigQuery)

[I am aware of [Export json from Firestore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617960/export-json-from-firestore) previous question, but seeing that I find no confirmation since last year and cannot find verification on Google Documentation, I ask again)

Else, is there any other format that is not Google-specific in which Firestore backups can be exported?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you read in that other question is the only Google-provided solution for exporting data.  (Note that it's not exactly a "backup" - it's an export, and it's not necessarily going to represent a snapshot in time.)

Any other solution will necessarily have to query every single collection and subcollection for all documents, and write the contents of those documents in the desired format, correctly handling each of the different field types.  Since recommendations for tools are off-topic for Stack Overflow, I suggest doing a web search for tools that might be suitable for you.