# export data from firebase cloud firestore to json file

Tags: flutter

I have a flutter project linked to firebase. I want to export my data to a json/csv file. I have found a away to do this when using real-time database but I am using cloud firestore. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: you can see this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46617960/export-json-from-firestore